# Is there a commonly used name for this weakening of the Archimedean property?

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, order-theory

Suppose that $R$ is a partially ordered commutative ring.
The order behaves nicely: We have $0 \leq 1$. If $a \leq b$ and $c > 0$, then $a + c \leq b + c$ and $a \cdot c \leq b \cdot c$.
For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ define $\hat{n} = 1 + \cdots + 1$(n terms), where $1$ is the ring's multiplicative identity. The property of the ring is:

For all $r \in R$ such that $r > 0$ is an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that either $1 < \hat{n} \cdot r$ or $\hat{n} \cdot r \nleq 1$.

The first case is like the Archimedean property. The second case says there are none of the usual infinitesimals.

If this property has a commonly used name, I would like to know it. Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what Exactly you want here. When we have either "$(1 \lt \hat{n} \cdot r)$" or "$(\hat{n} \cdot r \not \leq 1)\equiv(1 \lt \hat{n} \cdot r)$" , we have the Same Equivalent Statement.

Comment: The order is a partial order not a total order.

Comment: One Statement says , we can multiply a number such that we get a number larger than 1. Other Statement says , we can multiply a number such that we get a number which is not less than 1 , which means it is larger than 1. **Seems Equivalent , though I might be wrong.** Thinking !

Comment: @Prem In a partial order items can be incomparable.

Comment: I realize that , but I see "$\le$" , "$\gt$" , "$\not \le$" , where it is not clear which is the Partial Order. In Case that is a valid objection **(I am not sure)** , maybe you could edit it such that you use only that Partial Order through-out. In Case that is not a valid objection , you can leave it unchanged & maybe somebody will Post some Answer !

Comment: @Prem: $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ with the product order is an example of a partially ordered ring, which is "weakly Archimedean", but not Archimedean.

Comment: @Prem I guess my writing wasn't clear. The partial order is denoted by $\leq$. If it is not the case that $p \leq q$, then write $p \nleq q$. If $p \nleq q$, there are two possibilities: either (1) $p$ is greater than $q$ written as $p > q$ or $q < p$ or (2) $p$ and $q$ are incomparable.

Comment: That makes sense , @Jay , though I think it should be [ either (1) $p \le q$ or (2) $q \le p$ or (3) neither ] , where we avoid using $\lt$ & $\gt$ which are unused / unnecessary / undefined here.

Comment: Oh , I like that Example , @Ulli , thank you !